# How i parse belowed json Array in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript

```
[
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "pratik"
  },
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Name": "pratiksha"
  },
  {
    "ID": 7,
    "Name": "pratikshaman"
  }
]
```

I want to display  only : 6 Pratiksha

Comment: Java !== JavaScript, so what is it?

Comment: Iterate and look for ID = 6? If you'redoing this often, with a large array, put into a hash?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Not too clear on what your trying to achieve... is this what your wanting?

```
    //The json string
var jsonString = '[{"ID":5,"Name":"pratik"},{"ID":6,"Name":"pratiksha"},{"ID":7,"Name":"pratikshaman"}]',
    //The json array
    jsonArray = JSON.parse(jsonString),
    //search function to returns entry by id
    jsonSearch = function(id){
        return jsonArray.filter(function(obj){
            return obj.ID === id;
        });
    };
console.log(jsonSearch(6)); //Array contains your Pratiksha object and any other matches
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/uckpL5bt/**